# CASE statement between two tables (Advanced)

Tags: php, mysql, case, case-statement

I wasn't sure how else to do this, I'm assuming a CASE statement but let me know if there's a better way.

I have two tables that keep track of race horses. Once keeps track of their information, the other their race results. Some of these horses are going to be bred. In order to be bred, they must be 3 years of age or older, and they must have have raced that year or the year before.

For example - Stratosphere was born in 2000, she is eligible for breeding starting 2003. However, she raced in 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005 and 2006. This means her "Open Years" are 2008, 2009, 2010, etc. etc.

I'm not sure how to make a case for this, because it would be something like (from Horses table) YOB+3, and take into account from v_testhorse (where the records are) last DATE +1 year AND that there are no foals that year (HorseID does NOT equal DamID or SireID).

My goal is to have it displayed like this - 
HorseName, YOB, Gender, YEARS OPEN (this is the value I'm trying to create)

Thanks in advance - let me know if you need any more info!

EDIT: Table structure-
Horses:
HID (ID number, unique to each horse)   HName (Horse Name)  YOB     Gender  Sire    SireID  Dam     DamID   Type    OName   Stable

Results:

- Options
  SID (ShowID, unique to each show)   SName   Date (as 00-00-0000)    Host    CName   Grade   Gender  Year    Place   Tokens  Earnings    HName

EDIT EDIT: THe SqFiddle is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e1ad6 but if it doesn't work here's the code I used. I only entered a few values because both DB are pretty big, but here's one horse to test out!

```html
CREATE TABLE Horses 
(HID INT(11), 
 HName VARCHAR(225), 
 YOB YEAR, 
 Sire VARCHAR(225), 
 SireID INT(5), 
 Dam VARCHAR(225), 
 DamID INT(5) );

INSERT INTO Horses (HID, HName, YOB, Sire, SireID, Dam, DamID)
VALUES ('17578','Stratosphere','2001','Stonebridge First', '464', 'Cloud Nine', '6714');
INSERT INTO Horses (HID, HName, YOB, Sire, SireID, Dam, DamID)
VALUES ('36791','Troposphere','2012','Trapper Joe', '36595', 'Stratosphere', '17578');
INSERT INTO Horses (HID, HName, YOB, Sire, SireID, Dam, DamID)
VALUES ('38249','Xalena','2011','Arlin', '31886', 'Stratosphere', '17578');


CREATE TABLE Results 
(HID INT(11), 
 HName VARCHAR(225), 
 Date2 DATE, 
 CName VARCHAR(225), 
 SName VARCHAR(225), 
 ShowID INT(5) );
 
INSERT INTO Results (HID, HName, Date2, CName, SName, ShowID)
VALUES ('17578','Stratosphere','2004-10-10','SHRA October Trotting Derby, 1 mile, 3YO Trotters', 'SHRA October Racemeet', '13');

INSERT INTO Results (HID, HName, Date2, CName, SName, ShowID)
VALUES ('17578','Stratosphere','2007-01-19','Snow Drift Trot, 3YO+ Trotting FM', 'SHRA Start the Season Meet', '889');
```

Comment: Did my solution work?

Comment: Do you mean "they must **not** have raced that year or the year before"? That seems to be the case from your example result. Also, where is the information about foals stored?

Comment: Nick - the foals are in the same table as the horses. I've edited above to include the structure of both tables

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @CourtneyDeer my initial impression is that you are going to need a static table of years, which you will join ... group_concat (year) ... where not exists (disqualiftying conditions) ... group by HID.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I like this idea a lot! I'm having trouble thinking of how to do this. I made a second table with the years - I'm a bit lost on the joining here. I'm still new to this so I'm struggling

Comment: Take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com. It allows you to build your schema, load some sample data, and run test queries against it... and then share the link so others can test it, clone it, modify it, and then share a new link that includes any modifications.  If you will create one of these, it will help us help you.  Be sure to select the appropriate MySQL version.

Comment: @sqlbot I added it to the post above!

Answer (score 0):

Considering two tables are named as `horses` and `race_results` something like below should pretty much do the trick.

```
SELECT * FROM horses
LEFT JOIN  race_results race ON (
  race.horse_id = horses.id 
  AND race.year IN (YEAR(CURDATE()), (YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1))
)
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, horses.dob, now()) >= 3;
```

*Conside the above as a POC, and you can implement it based on your tables structure.*

**Update:**

If you want to change your column datatype, just creat another column `Date2` with the correct datatype, and then run the following query, once you cross check all the values are correct in `Date2` column, you can drop the `Date` column.

```
UPDATE table_name SET Date2 = STR_TO_DATE(
  CONCAT(
    LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Date,',',1), length(Date)-2)), 
    " ",
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Date,',',-1)
  ), '%M %d %Y'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! However, it doesn't return any results.

The foals/offspring are stored in the same table as Horses. So basically Horses is a giant list of every horse, listing their sire(father), sireID, dam (mother) and damID. This is how I've been linking things previously.

Comment: Ok, if you could provide an sqlfiddle it would greatly increase your chances of finding a solution.

Comment: I think the problem is the person who set up my table did not set up the "Date" as a Date field, it's currently as a VarChar and listed like so: October 10th, 2014. Any suggestions on how to switch this to a date format?

Comment: @CourtneyDeer Updated my answer.

Comment: SO I figured out part of my result, but part two I'm stuck on. For the races, I used the following -
SELECT *, 
sum(YEAR(`Date2`) = 2003) as '2003',
sum(YEAR(`Date2`) = 2004) as '2004',
etc. etc

I'm having problems with the foals, I'm using this code - SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(`YOB`) = 2012 AND (`SireID` = `HID` OR `DamID` = `HID`) THEN 1 END) AS '2012' FROM Horses WHERE HName = 'Stratosphere'   
And getting "NULL" I tried "SUM" And "COUNT" - any ideas?